# Parse.Cloud.beforeSave not able to set a new field on an object being created

Tags: javascript, parse-server, mlab, heroku-api, parse-cloud-code

I have a little problem in a `Parse.Cloud.beforeSave` function on `Parse-Server`. This line is puzzling me:

```
request.object.set("dbCount", 0);
```

It has been working before. But since I made a server update, to be on the *heroku-18* stack, as requested by `HEROKU` (*cedar-14* stack going end-of-life). It no longer works.

The purpose of this line is to stick a counter initialized to zero when a new item is stored in the database. But though the item is created as it should, the field "dbCount" is missing. Why is that? And what is the right code to create the field?

For reference, here is the relevant code of the beforeSave function:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("TheCollection", async (request) => {
 if (!request.object.isNew()) return;
 var query;
 query = new Parse.Query("TheCollection");
 query.equalTo("TITLE",request.object.get("TITLE"));

 await query.find().then
 (function(resUnit) {
  // If there is already a Unit with the same Title, we return an error.
  if (resUnit.length) throw "TITLE-USED";

  var query;
  query = new Parse.Query("TheCollection");
  var token = request.user.getSessionToken();
  query.find({sessionToken: token}).then
  (function(resUnit) {
    ... some useful processing ...
    // This next line is not working as it used to.
    request.object.set("dbCount", 0);
   });
  });
 });
```

Comment: try to change `query.find({sessionToken: token}).then` to `return query.find({sessionToken: token}).then`

Comment: I just tried. You were right. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you are missing a "return" and the save is happening before your promise resolves.
I also see that you are using the same variable "resUnit" in nested scope which might be confusing it's use.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("TheCollection", async (request) => {
 if (!request.object.isNew()) return;
 var query;
 query = new Parse.Query("TheCollection");
 query.equalTo("TITLE",request.object.get("TITLE"));

 await query.find().then
 (function(resUnit) {
  // If there is already a Unit with the same Title, we return an error.
  if (resUnit.length) throw "TITLE-USED";

  var query;
  query = new Parse.Query("TheCollection");
  var token = request.user.getSessionToken();
  >>>> return <<<<< query.find({sessionToken: token}).then
  (function(resUnit) {
    ... some useful processing ...
    // This next line is not working as it used to.
    request.object.set("dbCount", 0);
   });
  });
 });
```

If you want to go a step further, I would take full advantage of async and await to flatten out your code like so. by using flat code you can eliminate a lot of the clutter that allows for bugs

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("TheCollection", async (request) => {
 if (!request.object.isNew()) return;
 const query = new Parse.Query("TheCollection");
 query.equalTo("TITLE",request.object.get("TITLE"));

 const resUnit1 = await query.first()
 // If there is already a Unit with the same Title, we return an error.
 if (resUnit) throw "TITLE-USED";

  const query2 = new Parse.Query("TheCollection");
  const resUnit2 = await query2.find({sessionToken: request.user.getSessionToken()})
  ... some useful processing ...
  request.object.set("dbCount", 0);
 });
```

Comment: I accept the only (and right) answer here. But I suppose in a way the credit should go to  Davi Macêdo who gave the same (short) reply in  a comment earlier. Thanks to both.